# OpenGL 3.0 is not supported by the OpenGL driver - RizomUV

Tags: opengl, uv-mapping, driver

I have a problem with RizomUV 2022.0. When the program starts, it comes up with pop-up "OpenGL 3.0 is not supported by the OpenGL driver", so I can't import any geometry and work. I'm temporary using **integrated graphics** and don't understand, is there a problem with unsupported OpenGL version or integrated graphics driver? Should I try to install an older (before 3.0) version of OpenGL? If yes, where i can find it?

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as I remember integrated graphics chips usually only have minimal OpenGL support. There is a program called "OpenGL Extension Viewer". This shows you the supported versions of your current graphics chip. Since OpenGL is implemented in your graphics driver, you already have all supported versions installed (if you have the latest driver). The only way to get around this problem is either to find a version of the used software that supports the GL version that your chip can handle or to get a new graphics card that supports 3.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two graphics cards, check if the control panel or drive on the graphics card is working properly
In my case, the graphic card control panel was deleted for some reason and I had such an error.